# how to make same width of various menus?

Tags: plotly-dash

I have datePickerRange(), Input() and Dropdown(), their width are different, like showing below(white area). Thank you so much for your help

```
dcc.DatePickerRange(id='date-range',
                   min_date_allowed=datetime(2020,1,1),
                   max_date_allowed=datetime.today(),
                   start_date=datetime(2021,10,30), 
                   end_date=datetime(2021,11,2),
                   style = {
                        'font-size': '3px','display': 'inline-block', 'border-radius' : '2px', 
                        'border' : '1px solid #ccc', 'color': '#333', 
                        'border-spacing' : '0', 'border-collapse' :'separate'
                        } 
                    )
]
),

dbc.Label('DTS Heatmap Start Time:'),
dcc.Input(id="starttime", type="text", value='00:00',placeholder='22:00'),
dbc.Label('DTS Heatmap End Time:'),
dcc.Input(id="endtime", type="text",  value='00:00',placeholder='18:00'),

dbc.Label('DTS Data Frequency'),
dcc.Dropdown(id='data-frequency-dropdown',
         options=[
                 {'label':'Minutes','value':'Minutes'},
                 {'label':'Daily','value':'Daily'},
                 {'label':'Weekly','value':'Weekly'},
                 {'label':'Monthly','value':'Monthly'},
                 ],
         value='Minutes',                         
        ),
```

How to make their width the same? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the same width for both components, you can add CSS styling using the `width` attribute. So if you want to set an explicit width for both components, you can do something like:

```py
dcc.DatePickerRange(id='date-range',
    min_date_allowed=dt(2020,1,1),
    max_date_allowed=dt.today(),
    start_date=dt(2021,10,30), 
    end_date=dt(2021,11,2),
    style = {
        'font-size': '3px','display': 'inline-block', 'border-radius' : '2px', 
        'border' : '1px solid #ccc', 'color': '#333', 
        'border-spacing' : '0', 'border-collapse' :'separate',
        # New CSS styling for width
        'width':'500px'
        } 
)

dcc.Input(
    id="starttime",
    type="text",
    value='00:00',
    placeholder='22:00',
    # New CSS styling for width
    style={'width':'500px'}
)
```

Please note that if you give the `DatePickerRange` component a width larger than what it needs to display the date ranges, then it'll show some extra padding that may seem undesirable. If you want to give the input the exact width that the `DatePickerRange` has by default, then give it `"width":"288px"` , as this is approximately the default width `DatePickerRange` has.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, can I use width=100% instead of using pixels? also can I set this style={'width':}, outside the children of html.div() so I only need to define one instead of one for each component?

Comment: Yes you can use percentages as well, and yes you can apply to the entire div that the components sit in if you want to apply it to a group of components rather than each one separately.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried, datepickerrange() doesn't work still not cover 100% width ,maybe it covers 97% of width, what might go wrongs? border? I have multiple parameters for borders. which one should I remove? Thanks

Comment: Yeah it seems that 100% for width on the parent div doesnt achieve what you what, perhaps try using pixels and see if that solves your issue. Worst case is you apply the width to the components separately